# Can a Storyboard be controlled without starting it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I'd like to check if a `Storyboard` has been started before I start it in C#. Of course, any attempts to use `GetCurrentState()`, `GetCurrentProgress()` will result in an exception if you haven't used `storyboardInstance.Begin(FrameworkElement, FrameworkElementTemplate, isControllable)`. The problem is that I do not want to start the storyboard.

Documentation is pretty thin on this subject, and Google queries yield few results, so I can only assume I am abusing this functionality. The only manner of checking the state I can think of is to catch the exception, but this just seems so terrible.

Any better ideas out there?

---

Example to satisfy requirements

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock">
  <TextBlock.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SomeFakeEventICreated">
      <BeginStoryboard x:Name="storyBoard">
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:10"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundLogo"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="1" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:10" Value="1" />
          </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </TextBlock.Triggers>
<TextBlock>

public void DoSomethingStoryboardy(){
  // EXAMPLE OF FAILURE
  if (GetProgress() == 0.0d) // Exception
    BeginStoryboard(); 

  // EXAMPLE OF SUCCESS
  // but what a shameful way to do this
  double progress = 0.0d;
  try { 
    progress = GetProgress();
  } catch { }
  if (progress == 0.0d)
    BeginStoryboard();
  else PauseStoryboard();
}

public void GetProgress() {
   // Pass in containing object 
   double progress = storyBoard.Storyboard.GetCurrentProgress(textBlock);
   // Exception is thrown: Cannot perform action because the specified Storyboard was not applied to this object for interactive control.
   // This behavior is exactly as you'd expect, because the documentation states it needs to be controllable before you can call any of these "Get...()" methods. 
}

public void BeginStoryboard() {
  // Only Begin() allows setting IsControllable
  storyBoard.Storyboard.Begin(containingObject: textBlock, frameworkElementTemplate: null, isControllable: true);
  // Storyboard control after Begin() works fine because it has started already
  double progress = storyBoard.Storyboard.GetCurrentProgress(textBlock);
}

public void PauseStoryboard() {
  storyBoard.Storyboard.Pause(textBlock);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like seeing if [Clock.CurrentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.clock.currentstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is Active? Sounds like a tough scenario.

Comment: @ChrisW. The only way I can see to access that from my context is to use Storyboard.CreateClock(), at which point I'm concerned about that being inaccurate. Just to note, it *does* work to catch the exception and return an deduced value of "zero progress". Subsequent calls to control the storyboard are perfectly functional after storyboard.Begin(isControllable).  I will play around with your suggestion a bit and see what happens.

Comment: Yea I've never ran into what you're trying to do, kind of curious. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is the only way to query a storyboard state without starting it. Any attempt to query a storyboard (using `storyboard.Get...()`) before has been started in C# using the IsControllable override *will* result in an exception. The following code is as close as you can get based on my research through MSDN documentation.

**Code**

```
double progress = 0.0d;
try { 
  progress = GetProgress(); // Query storyboard status
} catch {
  // Do nothing if the exception is thrown, we knew this would happen
}
if (progress == 0.0d)
  BeginStoryboard();
else PauseStoryboard();
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `Storyboard`'s `CurrentStateInvalidated` event. As soon as it is called (going to `Active` for the first time) you know that the `Storyboard` had been started. Set a flag to remember that. Obviously, until then it wasn't running (your flag is false).